# SharePoint 2010 unable to get my custom groups

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a couple of groups in my SharePoint 2010 publishing site. I have some application pages where I'm trying to get

```
using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb curWeb = spsite.OpenWeb())
    {   
        SPGroupCollection groups = curWeb.Groups;
    }
}
```

It shows existing (default) site groups but not my groups.

Please suggest some solution with problem definition. I don't know why this is happening because when I try to access any of my lists using the `GetList("list name")` function, I never get that whereas if I try to access it through indexer like `Lists["list name"]` I get that list.

Somehow I can access lists of my site collection but not of the current website.

I'm not sure if there are some rights/permissions issues or what the issue could be. Please provide references if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `SPContext`, you can use `SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites` to get at this list of site collections. From the `SPSite`, there is the `AllWeb`s property for all webs and `SiteGroups` of the `RootWeb` for the list of groups. Please remember that there is no notion of a group in a sub-site

OR

```
using (SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Site.URL)
{
    SPGroupCollection collGroups = oWebsite.Groups;
    foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
    {
        Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oGroup.Name) + "<BR>");
    }
}
```

Comment: the SPWeb.Groups returns all the groups within the web that have at least one permission set. The SPWeb.SiteGroups however will return ALL groups

Comment: Thanks Syed! last line of your comment helped me in figuring out this issue. "The SPWeb.SiteGroups however will return ALL groups" groups which i created, didn't have any permission assigned. so thats the cause of the problem of not being listing in group list.